# How make $oController = new \MY_NAMESPACE\$oClass(); with PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I wonder how I can enforce this coding style
For now I just found the solution with eval()

```
eval("\$oController = new \MY_NAMESPACE\ $oClass();");
```

but do you have an alternative solution with better performance?

Comment: *Performance* won't be an issue either way. (Style will, though.) This smells of a bad design decision, though - consider elaborating why you need this in the first place

Comment: For example the cache system does not work with eval and safety critical

Comment: I'm not saying using `eval()` is a good idea, but just to clarify it's not a *performance* issue (I've seen people think that). But you probably didn't mean that anyway, never mind. But still - the need for dynamic class names may be a design smell in the first place. Care to elaborate what you need it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use eval to invoke namedspaced classes dynamically. You can build a string and use it in an instantiation context:

```
namespace mynamespace;

class MyClass
{

}

$className = '\mynamespace\MyClass';
$a = new $className();
```